# Image shown above text instead on same line

Tags: html, css

The displayed line should be image and text after, instead the text is displayed below the image.

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <img src="imgSource" alt="img">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">imgText</div>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <img src="imgSource" alt="img">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">imgText</div>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <img src="imgSource" alt="img">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">imgText</div>
</div>
```

edited, sometimes it all works fine, and sometimes it does not, first containing `<div>` always works as should.

Comment: Looks fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/716rnoum/

Comment: can you explain more in detail what you want to accomplish here

Comment: Your code is acutally showing the text after the image

Comment: You must float the inner elements

Comment: or you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/j19chpm8/

Comment: There's a chain Img + text Div elements, some work correctly some dont , there's no apprent diffrence between the blocks.

Comment: `<img ... style="vertical-align: middle;">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div >
    <label for="photo">Photo</label>
     <img id="photoPrev" src="" height="50" width="50"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
 <img src="imgSource" alt="img" style="float:left;">
 <div style="display: inline-block; float:left;">imgText</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

What about HTML5 features?

```
<figure>
  <img src="imgSource" alt="alt">
  <figcaption style="display:inline-block;">imgText</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Tnx, but not an option at the current used platform.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add this CSS style to your page

```
<style>
img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```

and then load the img as

```
<div>
<img src="imgSource" alt="img">
text-image
</div>
```

and all this will load image with text

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you are facing issue only few times on preview. I don't see any issue from my side.

Try to add **clear:both**

```
<div style="display: inline-block;clear:both">
 <img src="imgSource" alt="img">
 <div style="display: inline-block;">imgText</div>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;clear:both">
 <img src="imgSource" alt="img">
 <div style="display: inline-block;">imgText</div>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;clear:both">
 <img src="imgSource" alt="img">
 <div style="display: inline-block;">imgText</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but problem remains.